# Angular js application Databinding failed to Join Records

Tags: angular, entity-framework, linq, wcf

I am consuming wcf rest service into angular js application. I want to retrieve  two tables record and merge it by using account number .I want to join this two tables properties and display it into angular js application. But problem is when i enter the account number in input filed is not showing the expected record and failed to merge it .

Here is the Interface.

```
 [OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
UriTemplate = "/TranscationDetails/{Account_Number}")]
string TranscationDetails(string Account_Number);
```

Here is the implementation.

```
public string TranscationDetails(string Account_Number)
{
    using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities context = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
    {
        var CombinedQuery = (from x in context.Current_Account_Deposit
                             join y in context.Current_Account_Withdraw
                             on x.Account_Number equals y.Account_Number
                             where x.Account_Number ==(y.Account_Number)
                             select new
                             {
                                 x.Account_Number,
                                 x.Account_Holder_Name,
                                 x.Transcation_Type,
                                 x.Amount,
                                 Transcation_Type1=y.Transcation_Type,
                                 Amount1=y.Amount,

                                 // put other properties here 
                             }).ToList();

        var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

        return js.Serialize(CombinedQuery); // return JSON string
    }
}
```

Here is the Angular code .

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
      app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
          $scope.IsVisible = false;
          $scope.Search = function () {
              var post = $http({
                  method: "GET",
                  url: "http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/TranscationDetails/" + encodeURIComponent($scope.Account_Number),
                  dataType: 'json',
                  headers: {
                      'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                  }
              });

              post.then(function (response) { // .success(function(data => .then(function(response
                  var data = response.data; // extract data from resposne
                  $scope.Customers = JSON.parse(data); // eval(data.d) => JSON.parse(data)
                  $scope.IsVisible = true;
              }, function (err) {
                  $window.alert(err);
              });
          }
      });
    </script>
    <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
        Account Number:
        <input type="text" ng-model="Account_Number" />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="Search()" />
        <hr />
        <table style="border: solid 2px Green; padding: 5px;" ng-show="IsVisible">
            @*<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">*@
            <tr style="height: 30px; background-color: skyblue; color: maroon;">
                <th></th>
                <th> Account_Number</th>
                <th>Account Holder Name</th>
                <th> Amount</th>
                <th> Deposit </th>
                <th> Amount</th>
                <th> Withdraw</th>

                <th></th>
                <th></th>

            </tr>
            <tbody ng-repeat="m in Customers">
                <tr style="height: 30px; background-color: skyblue; color: maroon;">
                    <td></td>
                    <td><span>{{m.Account_Number}}</span></td>
                    <td><span>{{m.Account_Holder_Name}}</span></td>
                    <td><span>+{{m.Amount}}</span></td>

                    <td><span>{{m.Transcation_Type}}</span></td>
                    <td><span>-{{m.Amount}}</span></td>
                    <td><span>{{m.Transcation_Type}}</span></td>

                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the screen shot when i run the application and click the submit button with account number .it should display the record of account number 1 and merge two tables record but it's also showing rest of the record as well
[image]

Here is the database record where i have all the records with account number [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq to Entities couldn't recognize `Convert.ToInt32` as `IQueryable`. Because Linq to Entities builds a SQL query from your code and `Convert.ToInt32` can not be translated to query. So, you should change it;

```
where x.Account_Number == Convert.ToInt32(y.Account_Number)
```

to

```
where x.Account_Number == y.Account_Number
```

If `y.Account_Number` is a string type, I suggest you to convert it to an integer in SQL Server and EF entity.

**EDIT;**

Also, where clause condition is wrong. You are not filtering `Account_Number` which is posted from client side.

```
var accountNumber = int.Parse(Account_Number);//It could be better to use TryParse
using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities context = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
{
    var CombinedQuery = (from x in context.Current_Account_Deposit
                         join y in context.Current_Account_Withdraw
                         on x.Account_Number equals y.Account_Number
                         where x.Account_Number == accountNumber //Modify it
                         select new
                         {
                             x.Account_Number,
                             x.Account_Holder_Name,
                             x.Transcation_Type,
                             x.Amount,
                             Transcation_Type1=y.Transcation_Type,
                             Amount1=y.Amount,

                             // put other properties here 
                         }).ToList();

    var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

    return js.Serialize(CombinedQuery); // return JSON string
}
```

Comment: Why are you serialiazing the response manually. Dont do it. Wcf should perform it.

Comment: For both angular js application and wcf service

Comment: So, what is the response of request ? Does it return as unexpected ?

Comment: As you can see I am expecting join two table records and display it into angular js application. Return is list of record and respond format is JSON

Comment: I am asking you to what is the returned data ?